# 'long' object has no attribute 'title'

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I have json array that below it's one object:

```
{
    "comment_id": 10159,
    "new_id": 25208,
    "user_id": 1,
    "comment": "test",
    "liked": 0,
    "create_date": 1451268678,
    "is_mobile_user": 0
}
```

I need to get related news object to new_id and get related user object to user_id. I did it before but it didn't work now. I changed my serializer like that:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    news = NewsSerializer(source='new_id')
    user = UserSerializer(source='user_id')

    class Meta:
        model = NewsComments
        fields = ('comment_id','news','user','comment','liked','create_date','is_mobile_user')
```

Then i got this exception:

> AttributeError at /user_comments/1
>
> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `title` on
>   serializer `NewsSerializer`. The serializer field might be named
>   incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `long` instance.

Original exception text was: 'long' object has no attribute 'title'.

I tried to search. They said change child serializers with "many=True". But that makes my error to long object is not iterable. How can i solve my problem?

P.S. That is NewsSerializer:

```
class NewsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = News
        fields = ('new_id','title','short_content','content','image','create_date','type')
```

My News Modal:

```
class NewsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = News
    fields = ('new_id','title','short_content','content','image','create_date','type')
```

Than My View:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def user_comments(request,pk):
    comments = NewsComments.objects.filter(user_id=pk)
    serializer = CommentSerializer(comments, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: can you show your `NewsSerializer`?

Comment: Can you post your News model ? and how are you calling it.

Comment: @MertSaygı Can you also add a full traceback please.. Also are you trying to serialize or deserialize data? Maybe you can post input and expected output so we are all clear on the problem..

Answer (score 0):

You want to use

```
news = NewsSerializer(source='new')
```

assuming it's a FK on the model.

`new_id` is the FK value (i.e. the related object ID, not the object itself).

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are calling `title` in a `long` type literal, you can change your `CommnetSerializer` to this:

```
news = NewsSerializer(read_only=True)
```

if your `News` is a collection on `NewsComments`, you need to add `many=True` in `NewsSerializer`

Or create a method in `NewsComments` model and fetch wanted `news`